# SQLalchemy: Updating last inserted by id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables. Employee and History. Employee has a list of employees with matching keycodes. When an Employee uses the key to clock in, it gets added to the History with an in_time/out_time. The problem I am having is updating the History table row with the out_time. I have tried filtering by employee_id and last_insert to get the History id to update to. Instead it is updating every out_time as the same.

```
History
---------------------------------
|id|employee_id|in_time|out_time|

Employee
-----------------------------
|id|name|key


def update_location(id):
    return models.session.query(History).filter(History.employee_id == id).\
        order_by(History.in_time.desc()).first()

def out_update(id, time):
    History.update().where(History.id==id).values(out_time=time)

i = update_location(<employee_id>)
out_update(i.id, <time>)
```

Comment: Your code should work. Could you maybe share the class for `History` so that it is possible to reproduce your problem and then debug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are committing to session after making the update.

Otherwise the code you posted should work fine in this case.